# Gulp/Browsersync Can't access CSS/JS on external device

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I have browersync working perfectly on http://localhost:3000, but when I try and access it via an external device using the provided external URL (on the same network) none of the CSS/JS loads. I have tried changing the network file sharing permissions (Mac) to no avail. What else could I be missing?

```
browserSync.init({
    proxy: "local.website.com",
    injectChanges: true,
    socket: {
        domain: "localhost:3000"
    }
});
```

After a bit of reading I've tried updating  the socket as below, but still not working:

```
browserSync.init({
    proxy: localUrl,
    injectChanges: true,
    socket: {
        domain: "192.168...IP_ADDRESS:3000"
    }
});
```